# Timer using label

Tags: c#, timer, label

So, this seems to be a common question but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this. I have a C# Form application that goes out to an imap client and processes the emails. I want to have a timer formatted like "08:45" (for 8 minutes and 45 seconds) displayed on the form to let the user know how long it has been since they clicked the button to start the process.

I want the timer to stop once my process ends obviously.

```
private void btn_ImportEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    this.lblTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize) (this.timer)).BeginInit();
    this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimerElapsed);

    //connect to email and download messages...

    this.timer.Enabled = true;
    this.timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Start();
    for (int I = 0 ; I <= messages.count() - 1; I++)
    {
        //process emails
    }
    timer.EndInit();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lblTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
   // lblTimer.Text = string.Format("{0:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to solve this problem? Could you post any code you've tried?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: @SLaks: He wrote he has a C# Form applications, so I guess it is WinForms ;)

Comment: Edited with my code so far

Answer (score 0):

The following SO Q/A might answer your question...

[Display the running time of part of a program in a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220528/display-the-running-time-of-part-of-a-program-in-a-label)

I would recommend changing the format to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see is that you are using DateTime.Now which will give you the current minutes and seconds, not elapsed minutes and seconds. The second thing and the main thing is that since you are processing your emails in your main UI's thread you are preventing your label from being updated, you would be better off looking at using a background worker instead.

Edit based on Idle_Mind's comment *added DateTime Object instead of counter*.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    DateTime startTime;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted+=bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text =((TimeSpan)DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)).ToString("mm\\:ss");

    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int I = 0 ; I <= messages.count() - 1; I++)
        {
            //process emails
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark, Your "elapsed" timer will drift badly over time using that approach.  Either store the "start" DateTime and subtract it from the current DateTime, or use a Stopwatch instead.

Comment: @Idle_Mind. You are right, I was supposing that this would be for shorter intervals and was mainly trying to point out how to do his processing using a background worker. I will modify it.